# MS SQL Server - rename table name but don't change all queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to rename a table. There are a lot of different queries. Is there something like a global table alias? I want to have ability to use old queries. So I expect to use two table's names for the same table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`SYNONYM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE SYNONYM OldTableName FOR DBName.SchemaName.NewTableName;
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if synonym uses? In order to know that all queries were changed.

Comment: @BasilKosovan Queries will still access the oldName. They won't be rewritten. SYNONYM is like a pointer/alias.

Comment: I've got it. But my plan is to rewrite these queries and delete this SYNONYM  when I finish it. And I would like to know that it's safety.

Comment: You could check referenced object in SSMS, by right click and show dependencies. If they are application queries you have to search project in your codebase.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of places on the backend side. When I am searching in codebase this table name I see 100500 places that contain the same name as my table is.

Comment: @BasilKosovan Well, if codebase is using your table you may be able to use some refactor tool to rename all occurences(IntelliJ, Visual Studio, ...), otherwise you have to do it by hand :(

Comment: I understand that I need to do it manually. My question was: How to identify that none use synonym? Will be good if SQL server store this info

Comment: @BasilKosovan If by use you mean "reference" in objects like view/stored procedure then SSMS -> Object Name -> View dependencies, if application queries then I suggest reading about Extended Events/Audit

Comment: I mean .Net code(dapper and other ORM). Your suggestion is to create an event or run a profiler with a filter (text like '%tableName%'). It will be applied to all queries and SQL server will slow down